# Can manifest.json have both 2 and 3 versions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension, manifest.json

It seems that Chrome Store refuses to accept manifest 2, and FireFox does not understand manifest 3. That is, I can no longer create one extension ZIP file and upload to both Chrome Store and FireFox Store.

Is there a way to have both 2 and 3 versions in one manifest.json file at the same time?

Comment: No, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, a manifest file can only have one version defined.

If your extension works in both manifest versions, what you can do is have two `manifest.json` files (like `manifest_v2.json` and `manifest_v3.json` and then create two zip files, one using version 2 manifest for Firefox and one using version 3 manifest for Chrome. You do need to rename them to `manifest.json` before creating the zip though.

If you build manually, it's a bit of manual work to rename a file, create zip, rename it back, rename the other file and repeat. If you have some build tools included, you can automate that process.